# How to validate a belongs_to field's model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider the following two models

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_reports
  enum genre: [:fiction, :nonfiction]
end

class BookReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

I want to validate book_reports so that it only saves those with a genre of :fiction. I can add a before_save hook to check the book association's genre but am curious if there is a better way.

Comment: Why would you add reports to a nonfiction book in the first place? There's no context, maybe a better option rather than a callback is to just don't assign reports to the book if it shouldn't have them.

Comment: I used books and book reports just as a quick example to demonstrate the problem, but I do agree it is silly to assign reports to the book if that was the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use `before_create` callback instead so that you can catch the genre a little sooner in the workflow, but otherwise your idea is fairly sound:

Use a call-back to trigger a check on the genre, and if it doesn't match what you're looking for, reject the record and move on.

You could also use the `:validates` call-back to validate that `self.genre == 'Fiction'` or whatever else you want to check for, and use `before_validation` to catch it even sooner.

I recommend reading through the RubyGuides page on [Active Record Callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to understand a bit more about the workflow, and then use best judgement to decide when to actually check the Genre value you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [custom methods](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods):

```
validate :belongs_to_fiction_book, on: [:create, :update]

def belongs_to_fiction_book
    errors.add(:book, "is not a fiction book.") unless book.genre == "fiction"
end
```